# How to fix ERROR_INVALID_ADDRESS (error 487) returned by SymFromAddr

Tags: c, function, symbols, dbghelp

I'm tryng to get function name by address.

I'm using VS Community 2019 and my first step is to copy microsoft examples that you can find at:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/debug/initializing-the-symbol-handler
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/debug/retrieving-symbol-information-by-address

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <dbghelp.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "dbghelp")

int main() {

     DWORD64  SOME_ADDRESS = (DWORD64) (main);

    // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/debug/initializing-the-symbol-handler

    DWORD  error;
    HANDLE hProcess;

    SymSetOptions(SYMOPT_UNDNAME | SYMOPT_DEFERRED_LOADS);

    hProcess = GetCurrentProcess();

    if (!SymInitialize(hProcess, NULL, TRUE))
    {
        // SymInitialize failed
        error = GetLastError();
        printf("SymInitialize returned error : %d\n", error);
        return FALSE;
    }

    // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/debug/retrieving-symbol-information-by-address

    DWORD64  dwDisplacement = 0;
    DWORD64  dwAddress = SOME_ADDRESS;

    char buffer[sizeof(SYMBOL_INFO) + MAX_SYM_NAME * sizeof(TCHAR)];
    PSYMBOL_INFO pSymbol = (PSYMBOL_INFO)buffer;

    pSymbol->SizeOfStruct = sizeof(SYMBOL_INFO);
    pSymbol->MaxNameLen = MAX_SYM_NAME;

    if (SymFromAddr(hProcess, dwAddress, &dwDisplacement, pSymbol))
    {
        // SymFromAddr returned success
    }
    else
    {
        // SymFromAddr failed
        DWORD error = GetLastError();
        printf("SymFromAddr returned error : %d\n", error);
    }

}
```

But this code print always "SymFromAddr returned error : 487"...
I think I'm doing something wrong.
Can you help?

Thanks,
Alberto

Comment: I don't know this family of functions, but it seems strange to me that a process could debug itself.

Comment: Try it with the address of another function besides `main`.

Comment: @ssbssa No luck also if I try with another function.

Comment: @Alb, have you already got some solution to this problem? What are your Windows and SDK versions?